# Integrating JAX-RS and Java Servlets

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I'm a university student, currently developing an Android app for a module. Working on connecting it to a server to perform logins, etc. The department have given us a server to use and instructed us to use Servlets. I would rather do it a Restful manner, seeming as it's an industry standard. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

/**
 *
 * @author Tom
 */
public class Login {

    public boolean doLogin(@QueryParam("email") String email) {
        return checkCredentials(email);
    }

    private boolean checkCredentials(String email){
        boolean result = false;
        if (email != ""){
            try {
                result = DBConnection.checkLogin(email);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = false;
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I wrote another class, `DBConnection`, but this seems to work ok (using JDBC to connect to the MySQL database).

The problem I'm having, is that when I run the webserver (using `Jetty`, and `ant` is the build tool) and try to access the page on the server through my browser, it just gives me a 503, `Servlet not initialised` error. I assume this is because I'm not extending the `HttpServlet` class? Here is some example Servlet code they gave us:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Product extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

They've given us a file called `JettyStart.java`, which starts the web server when you run ant:

```
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHttpContext;

public class JettyStart
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //A server running at http://localhost:8085 is created
        Server server = new Server();
        server.addListener(":8085");

        ServletHttpContext context = (ServletHttpContext) server.getContext("/");
        context.addServlet("/path/to/Login", "package.name.Login");

        server.start();
    }
}
```

So how would I go about integrating Servlets into my Restful approach to communicating with the server/database? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an answer, but you may have better luck making your project maven-based and using the jetty-maven-plugin. I have, personally. It's easy to set up if you have an IDE which can produce a simple maven archetype. You just drop the plugin into your pom and run mvn jetty:run from the command line. Wiring up the JAX-RS web services isn't too complicated, you just give them the correct annotations like so:

```
package com.my.project.services;

// imports here 

@Path("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    @GET
    @Produces({"text/html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
    public String getLoginInfo(@QueryParam("email") String email) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And that should be enough to get them picked up by the jetty servlet container as long as your web.xml is set up properly. If you use a maven webapp archetype this may be done for you, otherwise you'll have to poke around a bit, but if it helps this is what (the relevant parts of) my web.xml looks like in one of my projects:

```
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.my.project.services</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myproject/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The mapping here is saying take the servlet-name "rest" and map it to the package com.my.project.services where all my JAX-RS services live, with the @Path value appended to the end (so the login service above would be located at /myproject/rest/login). You can set the mapping paths up any way you want.

edit: should mention my project is also using Jersey. Here's a good guide to setting up a project like this: http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This sounds better than using ant, but unfortunately the server is shared with other students, so if I changed the build procedure it would mean the other students wouldn't be able to use it. I'll look more into it though, there might be a workaround or something.